# How to use this JavaScript snippet twice on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With some help, I got some JavaScript working. It looks like:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $li = $('.eo-events li');

    $li.hide().filter(':lt(6)').show()

    var x = 6;

    $('#next, #prev').click(function() {
      var m = this.id === 'prev' ? 'first' : 'last';
      var $m = $li.filter(':visible')[m]()[this.id + 'All'](":lt(" + x + ")");
      if ($m.length == 0) return;

      var time = 250;

      $li.fadeOut(time);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $m.fadeIn(time);
      }, time);
    });
  });
</script>
```

What this does is take a group of list items and navigate every 5 list items.

This is working great, but I’d like to use this as-is and then also somewhere else, is that possible? I tried adding another script call which looks like this. The top part functions, which only shows a certain number of items, but the `next` and `prev` arrows are not functioning at all. The original set of list items is still working great, even with this second script call, but I’m not sure why the second set of `next` and `prev` arrows are not working.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $li = $('.new-list li');

    $li.hide().filter(':lt(1)').show()

    var x = 1;

    $('#next1, #prev1').click(function() {
      var m = this.id === 'prev1' ? 'first' : 'last';
      var $m = $li.filter(':visible')[m]()[this.id + 'All'](":lt(" + x + ")");

      if ($m.length == 0) return;

      var time = 250;

      $li.fadeOut(time);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $m.fadeIn(time);
      }, time);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I’m thinking I need to change a variable name. I have tried changing `x` to `y` and `m` to `n` and `$li` to `$item`, but it’s not working. I know this is probably a simple adjustment, any ideas?

Comment: Combine them into 1 `$(document).ready()` function...

Comment: With current structure all the variables are scoped locally within each of the `ready()` callbacks so there is no collision there. Not enough known to help solve issue. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I combined them into a single ``$(document).ready()`` and the "Prev" and "Next" links still do not function - https://jsfiddle.net/u3qffmnf/2/

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but this is the actual dev site: http://joshrodg.com/hallmark/ - the "Events" section is the one that works without issue, the second one is at the very top under the logo - the "Why Does Jesus Matter?" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you over complicated this line:

```
var $m = $li.filter(':visible')[m]()[this.id + 'All'](":lt(" + x + ")");
```

making it hard to spot problems

It would appear you are wanting to chain methods `nextAll()` or `prevAll()` but since the ID's  you are using in second instance have a `1` at the end you will end up with `next1All()` or `prev1All()`. These should be throwing errors indicating method doesn't exist

Comment: I thought by adding a 1 the code would look for the prev1 ``id`` instead of the ``prev`` id...but with that explanation I see how that would mess up ``nextAll()`` and ``prevAll()`` I have adjusted that line to ``var m = this.id === 'prev' ? 'first' : 'last';`` which should fix the one, but the next and prev links are still broken.

Comment: can do something like `var direction = this.id.replace('1,'')` ...then `[direction + 'All']`. Personally I would rewrite this to make the whole think more readable. Perhaps use classes or data attributes instead of ID for the logic so it is more universal, or use `this.id.indexOf('prev')>-1`

Comment: This works great! Unfortunately, I don't know enough about javascript to rewrite this function. I do agree, I definitely think their could be a much simpler approach by combining the two functions. I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u3qffmnf/4/. Thank you so much for all your help!